# Arithmetics and Number Theory

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Prove that 9 doesn’t divide (2^p)+ 1 always where p is a prime number larger than 5 knowing that this number is divisible by 3

Comment: See Lemma 2 in [art of problem solving](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h17326p118690). If $3\nmid a$, then $p\nmid 2^a+1$. Then take $a=p>3$ prime.

Comment: Recommend formatting with latex for your math when you post questions! https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/1053712

Answer (score 1):

To prove that (2^p + 1) is not divisible by 9 for every natural number (p), we can use a proof by contradiction.

Suppose there exists a value of (p) for which (2^p + 1) is divisible by 9. This means that there exists an integer (k) such that (2^p + 1 = 9k).

Let's consider the possible congruences of (2^p) modulo 9:

1. When (p = 1), we have (2^p = 2) (mod 9). In this case, (2^p + 1 = 2 + 1 = 3) (mod 9). However, 3 is not divisible by 9, which contradicts our initial assumption.
2. When (p = 2), we have (2^p = 4) (mod 9). In this case, (2^p + 1 = 4 + 1 = 5) (mod 9). Again, 5 is not divisible by 9, which contradicts our initial assumption.
3. When (p = 3), we have (2^p = 8) (mod 9). In this case, (2^p + 1 = 8 + 1 = 9) (mod 9). Although (2^p + 1) is congruent to 9 (mod 9), this does not imply that it is divisible by 9.
4. Let's assume that the congruence (2^p = 1) (mod 9) is true for some (p > 3). In this case, we have (2^p + 1 = 1 + 1 = 2) (mod 9). Again, 2 is not divisible by 9, which contradicts our initial assumption.

Thus, in all cases, we arrive at a contradiction, showing that (2^p + 1) is not divisible by 9 for every natural number (p).

Comment: I solved it but thanks for your efforts